# cXML PunchOutSetupRequest and PunchOutSetupResponse examples in C#

Tags: c#, cxml-commercexml

I'm trying to implement punchout catalogs on our eComm site. Honestly, the documentation for cXML is a mess and all the code examples are in javascript and/or VB.Net (I use C# and would rather not have to try and translate). Does anyone out there have examples or samples of how to receive the PunchOutSetupRequest XML and then send out the PunchOutSetupResponse XML using C#? I've been unable to find anything on the interwebs (I've been looking for two days now)...

I'm hoping I can just do this inside an ActionResult (vs. a 'launch page' as suggested).

I'm a complete noob at punchouts and could really use some help here. The bosses are being pretty pushy, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Suggestions as to how to make this work would also be much appreciated.

I apologize to all for the vagueness of the question (request).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't trivial, but this should get you started.

You'll need 3 generic handlers (.ashx): Setup, Start, and Order....

Setup and Order will receive HTTP Post with content-type of "text/xml".  Look at HttpRequest.InputStream if needed to get the XML into a string.  From there, look at LINQ-to-XML to dig out the data you want. Your HTTP Response to both of these will also be content-type "text/xml" and UTF8 encoded, returning the CXML as documented...use LINQ-to-XML to produce that.

The Setup handler will need to validate credentials and return a URL with a unique QueryString token pointing to the Start handler.  Do not expect session persistence between Setup and Start, because they're not from the same caller.  This handler will need to create an application object for the token and associated data you extracted from the cXML.

The Start handler will be called as a simple GET, and will need to match the token in the QueryString to the appropriate application object, copy that data to the session, and then do a response.redirect to whatever page in your site you want the buyer to land on.

Once they populate their cart with some things, and are ready to check out, you'll take them to a page that has an embedded form (not to be confused with an ASP.Net form that posts back to your server) and a submit button (again, not an ASP.Net button).  From your Setup handler, you captured a URL to point this form's Post, and within the form you'll have a hidden input tag with the UTF8 encoded CXML Punchout Order injected as the value produced with LINQ-to-XML.  Highly recommend Base64 encoding that value to avoid ASP.Net messing with the tags it contains during rendering, and naming the hidden input "cxml-base64" per the documentation.  The result is the form is client-side POSTed to your customer's server instead of yours, and their server will extract the CXML Punchout Order and that ends your visitor's session.

The Order handler will receive a CXML OrderRequest and just like Setup, you'll dump that to a string and then use LINQ-to-XML to parse it and act upon it.  Again you'll get credentials to verify, possibly a credit card to process, and the order items, ship-to, etc.  Note that the OrderRequest may not contain all the items that were in the Punchout Order, because the system on your customer's side may remove items or even change item quantities before submitting the final OrderRequest to you. The OrderRequest could come back to you after the Punchout Order is posted to them in a matter of minutes, days, weeks, or never...don't bother storing the cart data in hopes of matching it to the order later.

Last note...the buyer may be experiencing your site in an iframe embedded in their web-based procurement UI, so design accordingly.

If you need more info, reply to this and I'll get back.

Update...Additional considerations:
Discuss with the buyer how they want fault handling to flow, particularly with orders, because you have a choice. 1) exhaustively evaluate everything in the CXML you receive and return response codes other than 200 if anything is wrong, or 2) always return a 200 Success and deal with any issues out of band or by generating a ConfirmationRequest that rejects the order. My experience is that a mix of the two works best.  Certainly you should throw a non-200 if the credentials fail, but you may not want (or be able) to run a credit card or validate stock availability inline. Your buyer's system may not be able to cope with dozens of possible faults, and/or may not show your fault messages to the user for them to make corrections. I've seen systems that will flat-out discard any non-200 response code and just blindly retry the submission repeatedly on an interval for hours or days until it gives up on a sanity check, while others will handle response codes within certain ranges differently than others, for example a 4xx invokes a retry, while a 5xx is treated as fatal. Remember that Setup and Order are not coming directly from the user...their procurement system is generating those internally.

---

Update...answering the comment about how to test things...

You'd use the same method as you will for generating outbound ConfirmationRequest, ShipNoticeRequest, and InvoiceDetailRequest, all of which generally are produced on your side after receiving an OrderRequest from your customer's procurement system.

Start with [Linq-To-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) for an example of crafting your outgoing cXML (Creating XML Trees section). Combine that example with this bit of code:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

XmlWriterSettings objXmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
objXmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
objXmlWriterSettings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
objXmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
objXmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
objXmlWriterSettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

using (XmlWriter objXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, objXmlWriterSettings)) {
    XElement root = new XElement("Root",
        new XElement("Child", "child content")
    );
    root.Save(objXmlWriter);
}
Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

So at this point the StringBuilder (output) has your whole cXML, and you need to POST it someplace. Your Web Application project, started with F5 and a default.aspx page will be listening on localhost and some port (you'll see that in the URL it opens). Separately, perhaps using VS Express for Desktop, you have the above code in a console app that you can run to do the Post using something like this:

```
Net.HttpWebRequest objRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:12345/handler.ashx");

objRequest.Method = "POST";
objRequest.UserAgent = "Some User Agent";
objRequest.ContentLength = output.Length;
objRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

IO.StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new IO.StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
objStreamWriter.Write(output);
objStreamWriter.Flush();
objStreamWriter.Close();

Net.WebResponse objWebResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
XmlReaderSettings objXmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
objXmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
XmlReader objXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream, objXmlReaderSettings);

// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.  
IO.MemoryStream objMemoryStream2 = new IO.MemoryStream();
XmlWriter objXmlWriter2 = XmlWriter.Create(objMemoryStream2, objXmlWriterSettings);
objXmlWriter2.WriteNode(objXmlReader, true);
objXmlWriter2.Flush();
objXmlWriter2.Close();
objWebResponse.Close();

// Reset current position to the beginning so we can read all below.
objMemoryStream2.Position = 0;

StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objMemoryStream2, Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(objStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
objStreamReader.Close();
```

Since your handler should be producing cXML you'll see that spat out in the console. If it pukes, you'll get a big blob of debug mess in the console, which of course will help you fix whatever is broken.

- pardon the verbosity in the variable names, done to try to make things clear.

Comment: Thanks @MrGadget. Great answer. I will work through it and let you know how it goes. Should be a good reference for other newbies to cXML.

Comment: Extended my answer with additional considerations.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to test this on Localhost. My brain has gone numb trying to figure out how to send a simulated punchoutsetuprequest so that I can ensure I'm grabbing the correct values and sending the correct stuff back. Can you make any suggestions? I'm sorry if this question is incredibly stupid...I'm sure I'm missing the forest for the trees here and it should be easy to do.

Comment: out of curiosity - why are you setting the objMemoryStream2.Position to 0? so that the ReadToEnd starts at 0 index? If you'd omit that line, would the objStreamReader read from the end of the memorystream (current position) to the end of the memorystream (ReadToEnd) ?

Comment: If you go to the cXML website and download the dtd file, you can convert that to a xsd file then use xsd.exe to auto generate the C# Classes for setting properties. I've had problems with it skipping some class references (i.e. the cXML root node missing the Message node). It was a great start though if you want to use serialization to break apart PunchOutRequest and build PunchoutOrderMessages.