# cXML punchout handlers in a RESTful manner

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, cxml-commercexml

This is in the same context as this question:-

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515578/cxml-punchoutsetuprequest-and-punchoutsetupresponse-examples-in-c-sharp](http://cXML%20PunchOut)

What is the best way to achieve the RESTful equivalent of this? Can they be 3 API calls?

Comment: As long as it's indiscernible from the client, sure, but I'm not certain that's possible.  The CXML platforms aren't going to make API calls like you would if you were building both parts of the client-server system.  They will only do HTTP Post, they expect HTTP status code 200, and CXML content returned without any wrapping / envelope elements. Content-Type is always text/xml...forget JSON.

Comment: Also, CXML is chock full of XML Attributes, which the DataContractSerializer doesn't handle.